# Optimize innodb table: yes or no?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, optimization, innodb

I've always been using `MyISAM` tables in my `Wordpress` blog, however, recently I moved from standard MySQL to `Percona Server` and started using the `InnoDB` for tables.

Every time I run optimize I can see that `InnoDB` tables aren't optimized:
*"Table does not support optimize, doing recreate + analyze instead"*.

1. I searched about it and found some posts saying that optimizing `InnoDB` tables is bad for performance. Is it true?
2. Can I keep optimizing my `Wordpress InnoDB` tables monthly?

Comment: Why do you need `InnoDB` tables? Does your code use transactions or foreign keys?

Comment: @viakondratiuk: Because InnoDB is almost universally superior to MyISAM. Aside from supporting transactions and foreign keys, it's also faster, much more fault-tolerant, and generally all-around better. There is rarely any good reason to use MyISAM on current versions of MySQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Outside of some edge cases that you're unlikely to encounter, optimization is not necessary for InnoDB tables. I wouldn't bother.

Comment: So, it's totally different from MyISAM – which I had to optimize tables a lot of times. I just run a Wordpress blog on the server. I didn't have to worry about optimizing tables anymore?

Comment: Correct. Don't worry, just leave it alone and it'll be fine.